# OSSIM Alarms for Snort rules

Tags: snort, ossim

I'm new to OSSIM.

My requirement is to detect executable files (.exe) using snort. I have found a snort rule:

```
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "DLL Windows file download"; flow: established; content:"MZ";isdataat: 76,relative;content:"This program cannot be run in DOS mode."; distance: 0; isdataat: 10,relative; content:"PE"; distance: 0; classtype: misc-activity; sid:5000789;)
```

I added this in `/etc/snort/rules/local.rules` and Perl

```
/usr/share/ossim/scripts/create_sidmap.pl /etc/snort/rules/
```

Then restarte snort:

```
/etc/init.d/snort restart.
```

I can see the snort rule detecting the file download when I check the snort binary log in the snort console. BUT I want to see this alert in under Incident-> Alerts section in OSSIM web UI.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using forums.alienvault.com for these kind of questions - they tend to get more answers there.

What you need is a correlation rule. Try out the documentation  listed at the forums on how to write one.

Comment: I was unable to find any documents or samples related to this. Can you help me ?